# What kind of graphics is this?

Tags: html, animation, css

http://googleblog.blogspot.in/

The balls bounce as you move your mouse over it. Can anyone tell how is this done..

Comment: he did this with javascript :)

Comment: Use "The Force" - read the source!

Comment: @sandeep I thought it was c++. :P

Comment: @Filburt I couldn't get any idea from the source.

Comment: Well [they're **not** HTML5](http://www.aregooglesbouncingballshtml5.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each ball is a div made like this:

```
<div style="position: absolute; z-index: -1; border-top-left-radius: 400px; border-top-right-radius: 400px; border-bottom-right-radius: 400px; border-bottom-left-radius: 400px; background-color: rgb(68, 134, 197); -webkit-transform: translate(0.13934886012209222px, 15.280991621327088px); width: 40.078411732250885px; height: 40.078411732250885px; "></div>
```

The round shape is made thanks to `-webkit-transform:matrix()`;

The movement is made with plain javascript, capturing mouse buttons and maths formulas.

Comment: Have you checked the background image.. Each one is not a div..

Comment: Yep, [they are](http://i49.tinypic.com/34f1xxs.png)

Comment: Actually, matrices are used for transformations (here probably for translation). The round shape is made thanks to border-radius.

Answer (score 0):

Its purely css with round corner divs and some CSS3 trick